# How to correctly access URLs via @GetMapping?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm currently working on a Docker-deployed Spring application with an nginx-reverse proxy and want to access a subdomain via `@GetMapping` & `@PostMapping`.

What is the correct way to access e.g. the `/entity/add` subdomain?

Is this a code error or might my server be malconfigured? Is there anything else needed in order to correctly review this problem? I'll gladly add it.

I've looked up the official documentation, guides, other StackOverflow posts etc., but none of them seem to work.

> Controller.java:

```
public class EntityController {
private Repository repository;

@ModelAttribute("entity")
public Entity newEntity() {
    return new Entity();
}

// Overview.
@GetMapping("/entity")
public String index(Model model) {
    final Iterable<Entity> all = repository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("all", all);

    return "index";
}

// New entity.
@GetMapping("/entity/add")
public String loadAddPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("entity", new Entity());

    return "add";
}

@PostMapping("/entity/add")
public String submitEntity(@Valid @ModelAttribute Entity entity, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "add";
    }

    repository.save(entity);

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Overview</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Entities</h2>

    <form action="/entity/add" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="New Entity"/>
    </form>

    <div class="content" th:each="entity: ${all}">
        <h2 th:text="${entity.name}">Name</h2>

        <form th:href="@{/entity/details?id={entityId}(entityId=${entity.id})}">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
        </form>
        <!--<button><a th:href="@{/entity/update?entityId={entityId}(entityId=${entity.id})}"></a></button>-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> add.hmtl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>New entity</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="/entity/add" method="post" th:object="${entity}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                <td><input id="name" type="text" th:text="Name" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that a click on the `/entity/add`-form in `index.html` correctly links me to `entity/add`, but it just displays a 404 error. Same with other tested subdomains.

Edit 01: Title updated. (access subdomains -> access URLs)

Comment: Because `/entity/add` will only work if your application is deployed as `ROOT.war` which I doubt is. Use `th:action="@{/entity/add}` instead. Could you also rewrite your title as it has nothing to do with subdomains but merely access in regular URL.

Comment: these are just sub paths, but not subdomains. See: *west.example.com and east.example.com are subdomains of the example.com domain* - Subdomain, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)

Comment: Thank you, I updated the title. I tried using `th:action` as you recommended and I received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as you need to submit the form to this action url "/entity/add" with method POST. Consider using the Thymeleaf view templates for rendering the server side actions. Check with the following

1. Change the HTML action attribute to `th:action` attribute.
2. Provide the Submit action button to submit the form.

Check this url for more information: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Disclaimer: This is my comment for your question. As I don't have the reputation, I am posting as answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Prashanth.
I've changed the action attribute, but what exactly do you mean with "provide the submit action button to submit the form"?
I've also already followed this guide, but to no avail.

Comment: Please add <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td> after your name input tag in add.hmtl. By clicking that submit button, the form will call the action with post method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using thymeleaf for templating.

Add following in application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name: my-app-context-path
```

In Controller :

```
    @GetMapping({"/", "/index"})
     public String defaultPage(final Model model, final Locale locale) throws MyException {
            addGameInfo(model);
            return "index";
        }
 @GetMapping({"/match/{gameId}"}){
    --------
    ------
}
```

In view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    ....
    ....   
    <h1 class="text-primary">Featured Games</h1><a class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" th:href="@{/match/2944107874}">Game Info 2944107874</a>
    ....
.....
</html>
```

You should checkout [Thymeleaf Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

So your url will be resolved to

1.http://localhost:2223/my-app-context-path/

2.http://localhost:2223/my-app-context-path/match/2944107874

It depends on your context path, if you are not providing one, you can access mappings directly.